# Build an extension class by inheriting a python class in Cython

Tags: python, cython, subclass, cythonize

I would like to build a child class by inheriting a python class in Cython. It seems I cannot do it directly, as I got an error below. Is there any workaround for it?

Code (osmium is a third-party python package, which can be installed using `pip`):

```
import osmium

cdef class CounterHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    cdef list nodes, ways, relations
    def __init__(self):
        osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
        self.nodes = []
        self.ways = []
        self.relations = []

    def node(self, n):
        pass

    def way(self, w):
        pass

    def relation(self, r):
        pass
```

Error message:

```
add.pyx:22:32: First base of 'CounterHandler' is not an extension type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize("add.pyx"))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\osmium\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1102, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\osmium\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1225, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: add.pyx
```

I tried the Solutions provided by DavidW

Solution 2 Code:

```
import osmium

cdef class CounterHandlerBase:
    cdef list nodes, ways, relations
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
        self.ways = []
        self.relations = []

    cdef node(self, n):
        pass

    cdef way(self, w):
        pass

    cdef relation(self, r):
        pass

class CounterHandler(CounterHandlerBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):    # osmium.SimpleHandler
    def __init__(self):
        CounterHandlerBase.__init__(self)
        osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Dropbox (ASU)/Work/CAVLite/OSM2GMNS/V2/cython_test/tets.py", line 7, in <module>
    import solution2 as solution
  File "solution2.pyx", line 28, in init solution2
    class CounterHandler(CounterHandlerBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):    # osmium.SimpleHandler
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Solution 3
Code:

```
import osmium

cdef class DummyBase:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

cdef class CounterHandler(DummyBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):    # osmium.SimpleHandler
    cdef list nodes, ways, relations
    def __init__(self):
        DummyBase.__init__(self)
        osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
        self.nodes = []
        self.ways = []
        self.relations = []

    cdef node(self, n):
        pass

    cdef way(self, w):
        pass

    cdef relation(self, r):
        pass
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Dropbox (ASU)/Work/CAVLite/OSM2GMNS/V2/cython_test/tets.py", line 7, in <module>
    import solution3 as solution
  File "solution3.pyx", line 16, in init solution3
    cdef class CounterHandler(DummyBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):    # osmium.SimpleHandler
TypeError: best base 'osmium._osmium.SimpleHandler' must be equal to first base 'solution3.DummyBase'
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a number of options here:

1. Do you actually need it to be a `cdef class`? Have you got a real reason for this (beyond a generic, untested belief that "`cdef class`es are faster")? Maybe you can use a regular class instead? You don't look to be using any attributes that can't be represented in Python (e.g. C pointers). Remember that Cython still compiles `def` functions of regular classes, so there may not be the speed difference that you imagine.
2. Split it into the bits that need to be a `cdef class` and the bits that don't (this only works if the interaction with `osmium.SimpleHandler` is in the bits that don't):

   ```
   cdef class CounterHandlerBase:
       # code goes here

   class CounterHandler(CounterHandlerBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):
       # more code goes here
   ```
3. The restriction is that the *first* base must be a `cdef class` (which is actually a fairly strong restriction that's built into Python). Second/subsequent bases can be regular classes. Therefore you could create a "dummy" `cdef` base class just to fill that role:

   ```
   cdef class DummyBase:
       pass

   cdef class CounterHandler(DummyBase, osmium.SimpleHandler):
       # code goes here...
   ```

---

Edit: Based on the errors you report it looks like `osmium.SimpleHandler` is already an extension type written in C/C++. Unfortunately this means that is won't be possible to inherit from it in a `cdef class` because of restrictions on object layout that are built into Python (it's possible that defining it as an ["external cdef class"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#external-extension-types) might work, but it looks to be generated from [by pybind11](https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium/blob/000de57139f11cab1f22a99e7d9d3470f79f0947/lib/osmium.cc#L50) which makes it quite hard work work out the underlying struct).

Therefore, options 2 and 3 are never going to work in this case. Since it's written in C++ already I doubt that re-writing stuff in Cython is going to speed anything up.

Comment: the base class osmium.SimpleHandler has node(), way() and relation() functions, and I'm going to rewrite them in my class CounterHandler. The thing I missing here is I should use cdef when defining these three functions in my class CounterHandler. I hope I can get speed up when calling them. That's the reason why I need to define a cdef class.  After trying method 2 and 3, I got errors when importing the built pyd file. I listed the code I use and the error I got in my question above to provide a clear view.

Comment: Based on those error options 2 and 3 are never going to work (see edit). If you really believe you need a `cdef class` then I don't think there's a good solution unfortunately.